# How to know Block height when a transaction entered Mempool?

Tags: bitcoin-core, api, block, full-node, height

I'm hosting a Listening Bitcoin Node in Capital of Pakistan. I want to know the Block height when Transaction entered the mempool. Right now I'm using the time from the Json format of the Transaction and Checking the Block height against it. Do you guys think that this method is reliable or I fear that transactions in my mempool have more latency than usual node in Europe. Should use an Api to find the Entry Block Height of the transaction?

Please also suggest an api also?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bitcoin Core has a `getmempoolentry` command. This takes a `txid` and returns information about that transaction's mempool status. This includes `height` which is the `block height when transaction entered pool`.

Comment: Andrew I was talking about the historical data

Comment: @HaseebSaeed You should clarify that in your question. Historical data of this kind is not stored by Bitcoin Core. It isn't relevant or useful to node function so it isn't stored. But you could write a program which records this information for every transaction that enters the mempool. You could use the ZMQ interface to be notified of when a transaction enters the mempool and then use that notification to do `getmempoolentry` and save the information wherever you want.